# How much information can I access with facebook connect?

Tags: facebook

My google skills have failed.

My interest is how much user information I can access when having users connect to my website through. Comments, shared links, uploaded photos, data from other facebook applications used by the user?

Comment: As much as their privacy settings allow, but never their email address. What do you mean by "my google skills have failed?"

Comment: I failed finding the appropriate information, and had to recur on posting a question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) ..or the [old REST API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) for an idea of what you can access via Facebook APIs.

There's a good tutorial here: [Facebook Connect Tutorial](http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/tutorial.php).  I believe this article is using the REST API and the Javascript SDK for [single sign on](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login).